# Complications with rendering and compositing nodes

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, compositing-nodes

I'm trying to create a bloom in the Cycles render engine,  I believe I have successfully created it but unfortunately, I'm having some trouble rendering the new nodes:
[image]

Here are the nodes (notice the lack of the HDR)[image]

Here is the rendered image (notice the lack of bloom)

Thank you

Comment: Maybe in the Properties panel > Output > Post Processing, you have disabled Compositing?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be the problem, I have it checked

Comment: please provide your blend file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have added some nodes just for the viewer, but not for the composite node (which is responsible for render output)

Comment: Yes I've just realized  ;)

Comment: i was quicker than moonboots...OMG...i will celebrate the whole week!!! :D

Comment: *"I was quicker than moonboots*" Bless you, probably won't happen again for like... ever :D

Comment: @Chris aargh you got me this time you got me, but don't celebrate too much

Comment: It's cool, but the HDR doesn't appear in the final render. Why is that?

Comment: don't know - can u provide your blend file, so i can check it out?